# filtering describe-security-groups output

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm using aws ec2 describe-security-groups to get a nicely formatted list of the firewall rules on this particular security group.

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids sg-xxxxxxxxx --region us-east-2 
--query 'SecurityGroups[*].IpPermissions[*]'
```

The output is below.

```
[
    [
        {
        "PrefixListIds": [],
        "FromPort": 80,
        "IpRanges": [
            {
                "Description": "port 80 traffic from ar-router01",
                "CidrIp": "172.31.6.60/32"
            }
        ],
        "ToPort": 80,
        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
        "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
        "Ipv6Ranges": []
    },
    {
        "PrefixListIds": [],
        "FromPort": 0,
        "IpRanges": [
            {
                "Description": "this policy is pending",
                "CidrIp": "172.16.0.0/16"
            }
        ],
        "ToPort": 65535,
        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
        "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
        "Ipv6Ranges": []
    },
    {
        "PrefixListIds": [],
        "FromPort": 5432,
        "IpRanges": [
            {
                "Description": "psql access internally",
                "CidrIp": "172.31.0.0/16"
            },
            {
                "Description": "psql access from comcast vpn",
                "CidrIp": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32"
            },
            {
                "Description": "psql access from ATT vpn",
                "CidrIp": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32"
            }
        ],
        "ToPort": 5432,
        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
        "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
        "Ipv6Ranges": []
    },
    {
        "IpProtocol": "-1",
        "PrefixListIds": [],
        "IpRanges": [
            {
                "Description": "this policy is pending",
                "CidrIp": "172.31.0.0/16"
            }
        ],
        "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
        "Ipv6Ranges": []
    },
    {
        "PrefixListIds": [],
        "FromPort": 22,
        "IpRanges": [
            {
                "Description": "ssh access from comcast vpn",
                "CidrIp": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32"
            },
            {
                "Description": "ssh access from bt-xy02",
                "CidrIp": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32"
            },
            {
                "Description": "ssh access from bt-xy01",
                "CidrIp": "x.x.x.x/32"
            }
        ],
        "ToPort": 22,
        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
        "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
        "Ipv6Ranges": []
    },
    {
        "PrefixListIds": [],
        "FromPort": 443,
        "IpRanges": [
            {
                "Description": "port 443 traffic from ar-router01",
                "CidrIp": "172.31.6.60/32"
            }
        ],
        "ToPort": 443,
        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
        "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
        "Ipv6Ranges": []
    }
    ]
]
```

When I use the aws command on linux

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids sg-xxxxxx --region us-east-2 --query 'SecurityGroups[*].IpPermissions[*].[*]'
```

I got a little further but I'm kind of stuck from here.  I would like to see `FromPort ToPort Description CidrIp IpProtocol` in one line.

Any explanation will be appreciated.

Below is complete output without --query

```json
{
    "SecurityGroups": [
        {
            "IpPermissionsEgress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                        }
                    ],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": []
                }
            ],
            "Description": "firewall policy for the arkansas apache  servers",
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "FromPort": 80,
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "Description": "port 80 traffic from  ar-router01",
                            "CidrIp": "172.31.6.60/32"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ToPort": 80,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": []
                },
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "FromPort": 0,
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "Description": "this policy is  pending",
                            "CidrIp": "172.16.0.0/16"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ToPort": 65535,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": []
                },
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "FromPort": 5432,
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "Description": "psql access  internally",
                            "CidrIp": "172.31.0.0/16"
                        },
                        {
                            "Description": "psql access from  comcast vpn",
                            "CidrIp": "x.x.x.x/32"
                        },
                        {
                            "Description": "psql access from ATT vpn",
                            "CidrIp": "x.x.x.x/32"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ToPort": 5432,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": []
                },
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "-1",
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "Description": "this policy is  pending",
                            "CidrIp": "172.31.0.0/16"
                        }
                    ],
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": []
                },
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "FromPort": 22,
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "Description": "ssh access from comcast   vpn",
                            "CidrIp": "x.x.x.x/32"
                        },
                        {
                            "Description": "ssh access from bt-  xy02",
                            "CidrIp": "x.x.x.x/32"
                        },
                        {
                            "Description": "ssh access from bt-  xy01",
                            "CidrIp": "x.x.x.x/32"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ToPort": 22,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": []
                },
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [],
                    "FromPort": 443,
                    "IpRanges": [
                        {
                            "Description": "port 443 traffic from  ar-router01",
                            "CidrIp": "172.31.6.60/32"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ToPort": 443,
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [],
                    "Ipv6Ranges": []
                }
            ],
            "GroupName": "AR http policy",
            "VpcId": "vpc-xxxxxx",
            "OwnerId": "xxxxx",
            "GroupId": "sg-xxxxxxx"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the complete output without any `--query` statement? FYI, you can play with JMESPath expressions on [JMESPath Tutorial — JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html) -- provide the input JSON and then experiment with your expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
--query 'SecurityGroups[].IpPermissions[].[FromPort,ToPort,IpRanges[0].CidrIp,IpProtocol]'
```

To make the text appear on one line, use:

```
--output text
```

Note that the `Description` is *outside* of the `IpPermissions` array, so it isn't really possible to display it together.

If you really want to customise output, I'd recommend using an AWS SDK (for example, [`describe_security_groups()` - Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2/client/describe_security_groups.html)) and then you would have full control over what you would like to capture and display.